# React Query: get query status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

React Query has a useful hook called `useIsFetching` (see [docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useIsFetching)), which allows checking whether a given query is currently fetching data, like so:

```
const queryCount = useIsFetching(['my-query-name'])
```

I want to do something very similar: **I want to know for a given endpoint, if data has already been fetched (`isFetched`).**

I know this is returned from the `useQuery` hook, but using this hook would call the endpoint again, and I want to avoid the repeated call.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by utilizing `useQuery`'s `enabled` property, which allows defining whether or not to make the request.

```
useQuery(
    ['my-query-name', requestPayload],
    () => callMyEndpoint(requestPayload),
    {
        // ...
        enabled: booleanToIndicateWhetherToEnable,
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid calling the endpoint again by setting a `staleTime` on your query, because in that time, data will come from the cache only.

if data doesn't exist yet, it will be fetched. If you don't want that, consider `queryClient.getQueryState(['my-query-name'])`. However, this will *not* create a subscription, so your component will not re-render if the query state changes.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. Unfortunately `staleTime` won't help in my case, because sometimes I will need to check the query status *before* the query has even run. The second suggestion is interesting, but like you said, it doesn't cause the component to re-render on change, so it's not adequate.

Comment: two workarounds: `useQuery()` with `enabled: false` if you just need to check + subscribe to the result; or you call `useIsFetching(key)` just to get a re-render when the queries fetching status changes, and then use getQueryState. I like the first option better, as the second one will not inform you of updates done via queryClient.setQueryData for example....